# C issue with connect function for TCP client

Tags: c, sockets, connect

I having a problem getting the connect function to work. This code will compile but when I run the program I'm getting an error that I'm passing Invalid arguments to connect. I have tried everything that I can think of but nothing seems to work.Thank you for your help.

```
/*
* Creates a streaming socket and connects to a server.
*
* serverName - the ip address or hostname of the server given as a string
* port       - the port number of the server
* dest       - the server's address information; the structure should be created
* with    information
*              on the server (like port, address, and family) in this function call
*
* return value - the socket identifier or a negative number indicating the error if
* a   connection could not be established
*/

int createSocket(char * serverName, int port, struct sockaddr_in ** dest){

    int sockfd;
    struct hostent *hostptr;

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){

        error("ERROR socket creation:");
        return -1;
    }

    /* gethostbyname: get the server's DNS entry */
    hostptr = gethostbyname(serverName);

    if (hostptr == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", serverName);
        return -1;
    }

    /* build the server's Internet address */
    memset((void *) (*dest),0,(size_t)sizeof(dest));
    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",(*dest)->sin_family);

    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",ntohs((*dest)->sin_port));

    (*dest)->sin_family = (short)(AF_INET);
    memcpy((void *) &(*dest)->sin_addr,hostptr->h_addr,hostptr->h_length);
    (*dest)->sin_port = htons((u_short)port);

    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",(*dest)->sin_family);

    fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",ntohs((*dest)->sin_port));

    /* connect: create a connection with the server*/ 
    //if (connect(sockfd, &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) 
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)(*dest), sizeof((*dest))) < 0){

        error("ERROR connecting");
        return -2;
    }

    return sockfd;
}
```

Comment: That `memset` of `*dest`, you should look closer at it.

Comment: As well as at the another usage of `sizeof`

Comment: I see what you are saying it should be memset((void *) (*dest),0,(size_t)sizeof((*dest))); but that doesnt really fix the problem.

Comment: or even better `memset((void *) (*dest),0,(size_t)sizeof((**dest)));`

Comment: There are also other potential problems with your use of `dest` that could cause undefined behaviors. Like, where do you allocate memory for `*dest`?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `sizeof(*dest)` as the size of the address, but `dest` is not the address - only a pointer to it.

When possible, I'd recommend avoiding double-pointers, as they are often a source of confusion.

Comment: An even bigger problem is that the memset copies 0 to the pointer which means that the subsequent lines will access a NULL pointer.

Comment: I dont think that is the case because when I access the pointer from main the values assigned in createSocket are correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a double pointer, try to use `sizeof(**dest)` as the address size.